# Sun.security.provide.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException/: unable to find valid certificate path to requested target

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, handshaking

My java code is try to download jars from repository in and unable to download with exception i.e unable to find valid certificate path to requested target although I have all the certificate in the truststore .what can be the reason for such error .
I'm using vpn and proxy is also correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure eclipse is using installed jdk not eclipse default jre or go to eclipse forum for better explanation of the solution.i got the solution there only